# Double loop don't know how to get rid

Tags: javascript

I have a function that gets a number and has to calculate the multiplication for each number with the rest of the numbers in the sequence.

If the input is 10, it should calculate the multiplication between 1x1, 1x2, 1x3, .... 10x1, 10x2,  10x3, .... 10x10. (passing through all the numbers sequentially)

So I thought at first sight that I need a double loop to do all possible multiplications but for big numbers it executes following O(n*n) which is too slow.

I heard there is a way to use only one loop. Do you know any post related with this subject? The only ones I found doesn't take into count that I need to perform the calculation foreach number by the rest of the numbers of the array.

Here the code:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
   for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
      // do i*j
      
   }
}
```

Comment: _"The only ones I found doesn't take into count..."_ - So they have nothing to do with your problem. Why do you think there's a solution with just one loop?

Comment: One loop or two... That won't change anything on that `O(n * n)`

Comment: Is not a way to do this multiplication of all elements with a O(n) then? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if there is one solution with one loop is just that I'm trying to optimize at maximum.

Comment: _"it should calculate the multiplication between"_ - The requirement is not clear what the expected result would be. Do you need all steps `1x1`, `1x2`, ... in an array? Do you want the sum of all those intermediate steps? The product of all those intermediate steps? ... Maybe there's a formula for that, but that's a math question and will need a proper requirement/expected result.

Comment: Hi Andreas, yes I need the product of all those intermediate steps. I'm thinking more now that what I need is some kind of equation. Thanks.

Comment: Have you heard of recursion?

Comment: It matters _very much_ what is inside the loop.  i.e.:  what will `// do i*j` be in your real code?  It would be O(n^2) even just to _display_ N^2 numbers, so I don't know why you're trying to do better than that.

Comment: You need the product of all the steps?  `1*1 * 1*2 * 1*3 * 2*1 * 2*2 * 2*3 * ...` is (N!)^(2N).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with one loop (map), with the help of recursion.

```
const order = 10;
let sequence = [];
for (let i = 0; i < order; i++) {
    sequence.push(i + 1);
}
const getMulTable = (order, table = []) => {
    if (order === 1) {
        table.push(sequence);
        return table;
    }
    table = getMulTable(order - 1, table);
    table.push(sequence.map(el => el * order));
    return table;
}

console.log(getMulTable(order));
```

I'm not sure if this reduces the time complexity, but this is the shortest way I know of to doing it.